# Provide a type which has listed fields

Tags: javascript, flowtype

I write a function with Flow which takes a `value` of `MyType` and it uses only the field `foo: number`:

```js
const a = (value: MyType) => {
  return value.foo;
};
```

However, I want to make `MyType` work with any type which will have `foo: number` field, e.g. with such types:

```js
type A = {
  foo: number,
  baz: string,
};

type B = {
  foo: number,
  bar: number,
};
```

How can I define `MyType`, so it would work with `A` and `B`, but also with any other type which has `foo: number`?

I tried to do it with `$Shape<{ foo: number }>`, but it doesn't help, because when I provide `value: B` Flow starts to throw an error. Also I tried to do that as `A | B`, but I got the same error and anyway it doesn't cover other cases except `A` and `B`. Also I thought about generic types, but it doesn't look like they can help here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what I read in the official documentation, you can specify that the parameter you are looking for needs a specific field of a specific type:

```
const a = (value: { foo: number }) => {
  return value.foo;
};
```

This will accept any type (A, B, or any) that has at least the field "foo" defined (of type number).

However, if you only want your function to take a type A or B as parameter, you can use the following:

```
const a = (value: A | B) => {
  return value.foo;
};
```

Comment: Thank you, you are right, for the basic types it works correctly! However, I understood that in fact I want to solve this problem not just for type, but for an array of this type. And after some time I found `$ReadOnlyArray<T>` which cracked my case

Comment: The fact is I find the documentation pretty nice, clear and simple. I am glad you found what you are looking for